# Restart the application when some file changes

Tags: nestjs

In Nest.js application I would like to create some kind of watch which will restart the whole application when some external file changes. Naturally observing a file for changes is an easy part, but I don't have an idea how to trigger restart in Nest.js within the application.

Comment: like location.reload() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

Comment: Nest.js is a backend framework...

Answer (score 7):

According to the official documentation, the command `npm run start:dev` will launch your application and it will be recompiled when changes are detected.

The details are here:
https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/overview#basic-workflow

Comment: is there a yarn equivalent with this?

Answer (score -2):

To achieve the expected result, run the application in debug mode using the `debug` prefix for example `npm run start:debug`. To do this, you must have a script in your package.json: `"start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch"`.